# Какие есть варианты запомнить выбранный шрифт?

Tags: qt, qt5

Сделал выбор шрифта через QFontDialog, но хочу, чтобы выбранные настройки сохранялись при следующем запуске. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Comment: Нужно куданибудь сохранить данные о выбранном шрифте и во время запуска считывать их. Для этого отлично подойдет QSettings ( комент с ссылкой выше)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , благодарю.